# PowerShell Select-Object returning more than specified?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Why does the following command return more attributes than in the Select?

```
$obj = Get-VM | Select VMName,State; $obj
```

Output:

```
VMName         : blah-blah
State          : Off
PSComputerName : host
RunspaceId     : URI
```

And how do I just get the value for State?

```
$obj = Get-VM | Select VMName,State; $obj.State
```

The above should do the trick but doesn't :(

Answer (score 2):

That *should* work, but it sounds like for some reason the assignment of the results of **Get-VM** to **$obj** is happening before anything gets piped to **select**. Try `Get-VM | select VMName, State` by itself at the prompt, and if you get the expected results, try this:

```
$obj = (Get-VM | select VMName, State); $obj
```

To get just the **State** property, you can do this:

```
(Get-VM).State
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem found :)

The above command is just fine as it is, however when it get's wrapped in an Invoke-Command such that it's run against another machine then the results are modified to include run specific information and a 'follow-on Select' is required like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Comuptername XXXX -ScriptBlock {$obj = Get-VM | Select VMName,State; $obj} | Select State
```

Comment: It's a good idea to always include the actual code you're having a problem with. In particular, if you extract the part of a command or block that you think is making the whole thing fail, the problem might lie outside of the part that you've extracted, but nobody will be able to see that.